# Convert Xaml code to c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to convert XAML TO C# in the following code.

It is working fine in the design time.

but i want to assign the values in the runtime. Here goes the XAML code

```
<ListBox Height="550" Name="listBox1" Width="398" FontFamily="Calibri" Opacity="20" FontStretch="Normal" SelectedIndex="1" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Normal" FontSize="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" BorderBrush="#FF828790" Foreground="Red" OpacityMask="{x:Null}">

                            <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" AllowDrop="True">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding}" Width="288">
                            <Image Source="/final;component/Images/shawshank.jpg" Width="75" Stretch="Fill" DataContext="{Binding}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="75"></Image>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding}" Width="288">
                                <TextBlock Text="The Shawshank" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="22" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                                <Image Height="22" Source="/final;component/Images/fivestars.png" Width="100" IsManipulationEnabled="False" Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="0" AllowDrop="False" ClipToBounds="False" Focusable="False" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" UseLayoutRounding="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
                                    <TextBlock Text=" By:Frank Darabont" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to difficult. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: i want to add the item to my listbox fromthe code .but i dont know how to keep the same design for all items

Comment: i dont know if crate template for the list box can solve the problem

Comment: Can you mention your custom template in the question

Comment: it is borader and inside the border there are two stack panle one of them has image and the other has image and text

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert your whole XAML to C# to do this. If you want to set values from C# your control needs a name. To name a control do this in XAML:

```
<Control x:Name="MyNamedControl" />
```

Then you can do this in C#:

```
MyNamedControl.PropertyToSet = Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing would be to assign each of this control a `Name=""` and after that in your C# code you can access the values, using their names.

```
ControlName.Property = Property.Value;
```

This is a simple method you can access currently present controls or you can create your own control on the runtime and then assign value to them and attach them to the software Display.

Answer (score 0):

You can add controls and the property for the elements in the code behind like this :-

```
//Creating Controls    
ListBox l1 = new ListBox();
                l1.Height = 550;
                l1.Width = 398;
//Adding Property to controls
                l1.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
                l1.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                l1.Name = "listBox1";
                Border bd = new Border();
                StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
                Button btn = new Button();

    //Adding Controls to the Containers
                sp.Childern.Add(btn);
                bd.Child = sp;
                l1.Items.Add(sp);
```